# Print the name of the most recently modified file/directory whose name starts with 0-9 in the current directory

Tags: c

I need to write a simple program that prints the name of the most recently modified file whose name starts with 0-9 in the current directory. So far I can get it to print the name of a file that starts with 0-9, but it fails to consistently print the one that was modified most recently. I have been stuck at this part and I am in very desperate need to figure this out. Any help or hints would be of much help! Thank you!

Below is my code:

```
#include <dirent.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>  
#include <sys/stat.h>  
#include <time.h>  
#include <unistd.h>  

int main(void){ 
    // Open the current directory  
    DIR* currDir = opendir("./");  
    struct dirent *aDir;  
    time_t lastModifTime;  
    struct stat dirStat;  
    int first_file_checked = 0;  
    char directoryName[256];  

    // Go through all the entries  
    while((aDir = readdir(currDir)) != NULL){  
        // only check on directories with a name that starts with 0-9  
        if (48 <= (int)aDir->d_name[0] && (int)aDir->d_name[0] <= 57) {  
            // Get meta-data for the current entry  
            stat(aDir->d_name, &dirStat);    
            // Use the difftime function to get the time difference between the current value of lastModifTime and the st_mtime value of the directory entry  
            if(first_file_checked == 0 || difftime(dirStat.st_mtime, lastModifTime) > 0){  
                lastModifTime = dirStat.st_mtime;  
                memset(directoryName, '\0', sizeof(directoryName));  
                strcpy(directoryName, aDir->d_name);  
            }  
            first_file_checked = 1;  
        }  
    }  
    // Close the directory  
    closedir(currDir);  
    printf("The last file/directory modified in the current directory is %s\n", directoryName);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: You don't need difftime(), you can just compare the integral time_t values.

Comment: @wildplasser I understand this part. However, my code still fails to work as intended. Would it be possible for you to try running it and see if it works as intended or if you can spot the root to the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Works here:

BTW: you dont check for *directories*, you need to add a check for `d_type` to accomplish that.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){
    // Open the current directory  
    DIR* currDir ;
    struct dirent *aDir;
    time_t lastModifTime;
    struct stat dirStat;
    int count ;
    char thename[256] = "";

    // Go through all the entries  
    currDir = opendir("./");
    for(count=0; (aDir = readdir(currDir)) ; ){
        int rc;
        // only check on directories with a name that starts with 0-9  
        if (aDir->d_name[0] < '0' || aDir->d_name[0] > '9' ) continue;
            // Get meta-data for the current entry  
        rc = stat(aDir->d_name, &dirStat);
        if (rc < 0) continue; // check the return value!

        if(!count++ || dirStat.st_mtime < lastModifTime ){
            lastModifTime = dirStat.st_mtime;
            strcpy(thename, aDir->d_name);
        }
    }
    // Close the directory  
    closedir(currDir);
    if (count) {
        printf("%d files checked. The last file/directory modified in the current directory is %s(time=%u)\n"
                , count, thename, (unsigned) lastModifTime);
        }
    else {
        printf("No files/directories were found\n");
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming! Does it consistently work once you get to 9-10 files/directories? Would it be something to do with the fact that I am running VSCode with a Mac?

Comment: Count will overflow at 2Gig, I dont think you have that many inodes. (unless you are in bioinformatics) opendir()/readdir() is in POSIX, but file systems may differ. And VS/Microsoft is crap. It is designed to be crap. Bill G. just hates C.